# Testing Microservice with RabbitMQ mocked

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs, amqp

I am trying to test a microservice in isolation from other services. So far I have mocked all the external dependencies but I don't know how to run rabbitmq in memory. I need to have it in memory that is it cannot be available in docker or somewhere else. It has to be mocked in test only. It can be done in .net core using masstransit but I need to do this in nestJS/nodeJS.